# Problem with open pop up with the content of pop up on top when i had scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I open a pop up from my page, it works fine. But when I try to open the it and scroll to other position on page, then the pop up open accordingly the position of scrolling. I want it to stay on the same position of the page regardless scrolling.

Here is my code that opens the container of my pop up:

```
//open page
$('.single-page').on('click', function() {
  var selectedProject = $(this),
  toggle = !selectedProject.hasClass('is-full-width');
  if (toggle) toggleProject($(this), $('.page-container'), toggle);
});
```

Comment: Hi Spiros. Your wording is a little confusing. Could you possibly try to re-explain the issue again? What I am currently thinking you are saying is that the popup scrolls down the page when you scroll the page, and you need it to stay in the same position it opened? Or are you saying that you do not want the page behind the popup to also scroll while you try to scroll in the contents of the popup?

Comment: if I'm at the top of the page and open the pop up it normally opens, but if I scroll down to the page and go to open the window then the window does not open as before but it opens by just scrolling it to the content based on the scroll I have done on the page

Comment: if you want , i can send you a video of what's happening on your e-mail ......Thank's Spiros

Comment: Could you do me a favor and upload the video to some trusted file share, and provide the link instead?

Comment: ok i will do it on morning and i will send you.

Comment: Asyranok I have no way to do that, I can send it to someone mail or a social media chat please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LyZCfBDfytOG24Dk-QXGSvFfN1tLk8Rz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Asyranok here is the link with the video about my problem ....Thank's Spiros

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#popup').show().scrollTop(0);

$('#popup').animate({ scrollTop: (0) }, 'slow');
```

refere link : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp

I think it is scroll issue when toggle(open/close) second time it opens with previous scrolled position 
FIX :  scroll to top postion on toggle each time is one option